# I need to crop with OpenCV an image that I get from an input type file in an HTML form

Tags: python, opencv, flask, html5-canvas

I need to get an image from an input type file from an HTML form and then crop it with opencv, but I'm getting an error when I try to read with OpenCV.

HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="update-doc" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile01">UPLOAD</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="pic" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" id="inputGroupFile01">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-5 shadow">UPLOAD</button>
</form
```

Python Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, session, flash
import cv2

@app.route('/update-doc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def updateDoc():
   profileimg = request.files['pic']
   img = cv2.imread(profileimg)
```

Comment: I think pic is not your image file. What page do you grap?

Comment: Thanks Hermann, when I print profileimg I watch a FileStorage object but to use imread I need the path of mi image 'pic' but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Hermann that's just what I need, the name of input is 'pic' and I am getting a FileStorage object but I don't know how to get the path or find the path of the image 'pic'

Comment: Hermann ummm that's the path on frontend but in backend is different because the image is uploaded by the client in the frontend and opencv works on the backend.

Comment: Check the FLASK doc how to request a POST, [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#accessing-request-data)

Answer (score 0):

I think for cropping an image it's easier to use Pillow. But it is also possible with OpenCV.

FileStorage is a file-like object from which you can read the data or save it locally.
The following example shows direct further processing in which the data is read and converted.

```
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    request 
)
import numpy as np
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.post('/update-doc')
def update_doc():
    file = request.files.get('pic')
    file_data = np.asarray(bytearray(file.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(file_data, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Crop your image here and provide a response.
    # ...
```